# Finding the standard out for a perl program

Tags: perl

I'm redirecting standard out for a perl program. Example:

```
perl run_program.pl > /log/run_program.log
```

Is there a way to know what the standard out is. So in this case I'm looking to have the value of '/log/run_program.log'.

If it's not possible is there another/better way to get the same result?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The reason I'm not setting STDOUT in the program is because I'm calling a bunch of .pm that have print lines that I want to go to STDOUT with out having to pass the file to it.

Comment: What you wrote will redirect run_program's `stdout` (i.e. `print`s) to the file `/log/run_program.log`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know what file stdout is redirected to? Usually one writes a program to use a filename option that defaults to stdout if none if given.

Comment: The shell doesn't tell your Perl script what the name of the file is.  In general, the output could be redirected to a pipe and that doesn't have a name.  There's no easy way to discover the file name corresponding to the output file (you'd have to do a search of the entire file system to find the file with the same inode number, and that won't help with finding a pipe anyway).  Why are you worried about it?  If you need to know, make the output file name into a mandatory argument instead of letting the shell specify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system, you can use

```
readlink("/proc/$$/fd/1")
```

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: The reason I'm not setting STDOUT in the program is because I'm calling a bunch of .pm that have print lines that I want to go to STDOUT with out having to pass the file to it.

Just to let you know, you might be able to use the [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) command to redefine the FD for the default output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $output_fd, ">", "/log/run_program.log";

my $old_default_fd = select( $output_fd );

print "I'm now going into /log/run_program.log\n";

select ($old_default_fd;   # Restore the default when you no longer need it
```

This may work with most of your Perl modules. Just hope that they're not doing something stupid like:

```
 print STDOUT "Ha, ha. I'm still going to STDOUT.\n".
```

I hate it when Perl modules print stuff.

`<soapbox>`

To you Perl Module writers:

Perl modules should not be printing (unless that's their main purpose). You should instead return what you want to print and let the caller decide what to do with the output.

`</soapbox>`

Comment: I agree. but that modules are here and I have to use them. Unless I want to rewrite them... which it don't

Comment: The comment wasn't for you. It's my frustration with some Perl modules that insist on printing stuff instead of letting me handle the output. No, you shouldn't have to rewrite modules. However, that `select` statement can allow you to send output to a file even if modules do the print.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, no.  There's no way for the perl program to know where STDOUT is directed to.

The redirection happens external to the program, and is "wired up" before the perl process even starts.  STDOUT could be pointed to a device, a file, or another process (a pipe).

Comment: Not so. See my answer.

Comment: Ugh.  This works only if you're interested in system-dependent code.  I'd fail this in a code review with great prejudice.

Comment: You should be evaluating the code against the specs. If you're writing code that will only run on for a linux box, you don't need a solution that also runs on Windows. Failing a code review for using code that isn't portable is dumb.

Comment: Opening a file is system-dependent. (On POSIX systems, it's a system call named `open`. On Windows, you have `CreateFile` and `CreateFileEx`.) Someone just went and created an common interface. Feel free to create one for this purpose too.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of redirection from stdout to a file is to adapt a program which *typically* writes to stdout and redirect it to a file. The OS doesn't give you the name of the file, because it figures your program is too stupid to know what to do with a file name.

So your best bet is to get it as `my $file_name = shift;` and `open` it yourself. (A `shift` in the mainline pulls from `@ARGV`.)

Answer (score 0):

Give a chance to this ideas:

```
...
my $log_path = "/log/run_program.log"; # or using $0 in some manner
open $log_handler, "<", $log_path or die;
...
```

Now you could code a `myprint` subroutine that will call `print $log_handler` and use it into the whole program, or better, having a look to [OVERRIDING CORE FUNCTIONS](http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html#OVERRIDING-CORE-FUNCTIONS) you could self redefine `print` doing like this:

```
...
use subs 'print';
sub print { #redefine here }
...
```